# How to write data in Azure Blob storage programmatically?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am using below PowerShell script to read JSON data using REST API call from source. Now I want to load the data of $Result to the Azure Blob Storage. Any idea please?

```
$Params = @{
 "URI" = 'https://3ea5e53b-817e-4c41-ae0b-c5afc1610f4e-bluemix.cloudant.com/test/_all_docs?include_docs=true'
}
 
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```

Comment: check out the az.storage module.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-5.5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the issue, you can use the following ways

1. Save the JSON into one file then upload the file to Azure blob

```
$Params = @{
 "URI" = 'https://3ea5e53b-817e-4c41-ae0b-c5afc1610f4e-bluemix.cloudant.com/test/_all_docs?include_docs=true'
}
 
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
$Result | Out-File "D:\file.json"

$context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "andyprivate" -StorageAccountKey ""

Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File "D:\file.json" `
  -Container "" `
  -Blob "file.json" `
  -Context $context `
  -StandardBlobTier Hot
```

[image]

2. Directly upload to Azure blob

```
$Params = @{
 "URI" = 'https://3ea5e53b-817e-4c41-ae0b-c5afc1610f4e-bluemix.cloudant.com/test/_all_docs?include_docs=true'
}
 
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
Write-Host "the result is :"
$Result 

$context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "andyprivate" -StorageAccountKey ""

$container=Get-AzStorageContainer -Name "input" -Context $context

$content = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Result)

$container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("my.json").UploadFromByteArray($content,0,$content.Length)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jim. Same way can we load data to Azure Cosmos DB (Mongo API)? For example: directly upload to Azure Cosmos DB

Comment: @DineshMadhup If you have a new issue, I suggest you create a new issue in StackOverflow. Then you can tell me, I will help you.

Comment: Thank you! I have created new thread, please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66255263/load-data-to-azure-cosmos-db-mongo-api

Comment: Jim, is it possible to exclude "total_rows: 1, "offset": 0, and "rows". Because my source data doesn't contain that. I don't know from where these value get appended.

Comment: @DineshMadhup please try to the script `$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params

($Result.PSObject.Properties.Item('rows')).value | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: When I use this then I see this error for that line: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

Comment: Jim, Would you able to filter the $Result and only populate value starting from [ { "id": "US:111"  and so on...