# Filter JSON ducument using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-blob-storage

I have following code where I am reading JSON data from end point and storing in azure blob storage. The result data contains few extra line items which I don't want to store in Blob storage.

Current Result:

```
{
   "total_rows":1,
   "offset":0,
   "rows":[
      {
         "id":"7f8a1b1779693cfebcfd3686f24a424a",
         "key":"7f8a1b1779693cfebcfd3686f24a424a",
         "value":{
            "rev":"2-522bcd2edce6c1f1774f04cfaf3e86c6"
         },
         "doc":{
            "_id":"7f8a1b1779693cfebcfd3686f24a424a",
            "_rev":"2-522bcd2edce6c1f1774f04cfaf3e86c6",
            "productId":"33218896",
            "category":"Women's Clothing",
            "manufacturer":"Contoso Sport",
            "description":"Quick dry crew neck t-shirt",
            "price":"14.99",
            "shipping":{
               "weight":1,
               "dimensions":{
                  "width":6,
                  "height":8,
                  "depth":1
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected Result:

```
[
      {
         "id":"7f8a1b1779693cfebcfd3686f24a424a",
         "key":"7f8a1b1779693cfebcfd3686f24a424a",
         "value":{
            "rev":"2-522bcd2edce6c1f1774f04cfaf3e86c6"
         },
         "doc":{
            "_id":"7f8a1b1779693cfebcfd3686f24a424a",
            "_rev":"2-522bcd2edce6c1f1774f04cfaf3e86c6",
            "productId":"33218896",
            "category":"Women's Clothing",
            "manufacturer":"Contoso Sport",
            "description":"Quick dry crew neck t-shirt",
            "price":"14.99",
            "shipping":{
               "weight":1,
               "dimensions":{
                  "width":6,
                  "height":8,
                  "depth":1
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
```

Code:

```
$Params = @{
 "URI" = 'https://3ea5e53b-817e-4c41-ae0b-c5afc1610f4e-bluemix.cloudant.com/test/_all_docs?include_docs=true'
}
 
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
Write-Host "the result is :"
$Result 

$context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "andyprivate" -StorageAccountKey ""

$container=Get-AzStorageContainer -Name "input" -Context $context

$content = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Result)

$container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("my.json").UploadFromByteArray($content,0,$content.Length)
```

Revised Expected Output:

```
{
            "_id":"7f8a1b1779693cfebcfd3686f24a424a",
            "_rev":"2-522bcd2edce6c1f1774f04cfaf3e86c6",
            "productId":"33218896",
            "category":"Women's Clothing",
            "manufacturer":"Contoso Sport",
            "description":"Quick dry crew neck t-shirt",
            "price":"14.99",
            "shipping":{
               "weight":1,
               "dimensions":{
                  "width":6,
                  "height":8,
                  "depth":1
               }
            }
         }
```

Original Code:

[How to write data in Azure Blob storage programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66235423/how-to-write-data-in-azure-blob-storage-programmatically/66237832?noredirect=1#comment117164506_66237832)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66307286/edit) your question and add ther JSON in there **as text** not an image.Also, what exactly is the question here? Remove the extra items from the json or how to write data in Azure Blob storage?

Comment: Yes, was trying to find the way to remove extra item.

Comment: It comes like Result is NULL.

Comment: Actually, solution from Frank works for the contents from rows. I am trying now same approach to get the contents of doc only

Comment: `$Result = (Invoke-RestMethod @Params).rows[0].doc | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3`. Please, next time **do not add images** but formatted text. Nobody is going to type what you already have

Comment: Thanks Theo. I added formatted text in the question as my expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to my code:

```
$Params = @{
 "URI" = 'https://3ea5e53b-817e-4c41-ae0b-c5afc1610f4e-bluemix.cloudant.com/test/_all_docs?include_docs=true'
}
 
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
$Jsonobject = ConvertFrom-Json $Result
$Rows = ConvertTo-Json $Jsonobject.rows
Write-Host "the result is :" $Result 

$context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<your-storage-name>" -StorageAccountKey "<your-key>"

$container=Get-AzStorageContainer -Name "test" -Context $context

$content = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Rows)

$container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("my.json").UploadFromByteArray($content,0,$content.Length)
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. So the concept is if I want to see output of doc then can we simply replace ConvertTo-Json $Jsonobject.rows with ConvertTo-Json $Jsonobject.doc
For example Revised Expected output on my question image

Comment: `ConvertFrom-Json` is to convert a `string` to a `Json` object, so you can refer to the `Json` operation method.

Comment: Maybe you can try this `$Rows = ConvertTo-Json $Jsonobject.rows[0].doc`.

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json` is to convert a `Json object` into a `string`.