# Loop through REST endpoint to read document and write to Azure Blob storage

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

Using below PowerShell code to read the endpoint and write the result to blob storage. However, if the endpoint has more than one documents. How can we loop through each document and write the result as separate file (file1, file2....) in blob storage. If separate file no possible I am looking to store all document in one JSON file (FILE.JSON).

### For example:

endpoint-------------blob storage

doc1-----------------file1.json

doc2-----------------file2.json

and so on

OR above approach not possible then:

doc1, doc2...ALL DOCS========> goes to file.json

#$Credential = Get-Credential

```
$Params = @{
"URI"            = 'https://e832702c-faad-46e5-a585-885b8613c2ce-bluemix.cloudant.com/testdb/_all_docs?include_docs=true'
#"Authentication" = 'Basic'
#"Credential"     = $Credential
}

$Result = (Invoke-RestMethod @Params).rows.doc | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

Write-Host "the result is :" $Result 

$context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "genstorage999" -StorageAccountKey "<your key>"

$container=Get-AzStorageContainer -Name "blobcontainer" -Context $context

$content = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Result)

$container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("testapp2.json").UploadFromByteArray($content,0,$content.Length)
```

Code Reference: [Filter JSON ducument using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66307286/filter-json-ducument-using-powershell/66310976?noredirect=1#comment117258361_66310976)

Comment: I think you answerd it yourself . `if($result.doc -gt 1){foreach ($doc in $_){#yourcode}`

Comment: The code I have is only able to write first document of URI. I added your provide code just below Write-Host line. but it didn't make any difference. If i am wrong to add could you add in my code and past in answer?

Comment: I dont know what is behind `$Result` . You would need to check if `$Result` contains any value that can determine the number of docs retrieved from the API.

Comment: If you check the URI link in the browser then you can find the contents of $Result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your previous question and your description, there will be some rows in the result data and each `row` will have a `doc`. You want to write `doc` content to separate .json files in storage if there will be multiple rows in the request response. I assume your result data get from this link(a mock API just for demo): https://stantest1016.blob.core.windows.net/static/result.json, and its result contains 2 rows:
[image]

You can just try the code below to meet your requirement:

```
$storageAccountKey= '<your key>' 

$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName '<account name>' -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

$container = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name 'testc' -Context $context 


$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://stantest1016.blob.core.windows.net/static/result.json' 

foreach($row in $result.rows){
    $destBlobName ="doc_" + $row.doc._id + ".json"
    $contentText = $row.doc | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    $container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($destBlobName).UploadTextAsync($contentText)
}
```

Result :

[image]

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks Stanley. Appreciated!